# How to target elements within custom directive with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, functional-testing

Here's the custom directive I'm using:

```
<custom-select custom-model="newStuff">
   <div ng-if="itemsLoaded">
      <select ng-disabled="model.disabled" data-placeholder="test" class="select-search 
        select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option ng-if="model.placeholder" value="" class="ng-scope"></option>
        <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
        <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container>
         Has random stuff
    </span>
  </div>
</custom-select>
```

I'm trying to click on the

```
<span class="select2 select2-container>
```

But I'm unable to. How should I do this on protractor?

Comment: Please add your code (what you have tried so far) and the error that you receive

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with css?

`element(by.css('[ng-if="itemsLoaded"] .select2.select2-container'));`

Or just the class

`element(by.css('.select2.select2-container'));`